# Moving the fields and data from one content type to another content type

Tags: 7, nodes, commerce

I have created a content type called "ContentA" and in that content type I have two fields, "Summary" and "Title". I have already created a new content type called "ContentB" and it is also having the same fields. What I need to do is move the data and fields everything from the first content type "ContentA" to second content type "ContentB" and I'm using Drupal 7. 
I tried the [node convert](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_convert) module, it is allowing only each node at once, I am having approximately 500 nodes, I cannot use that module. So looking for any module/script for bulk transfer

Is this possible with a module or maybe from SQL. I don't know what to do, I've been trying to do this from weeks and I'm stuck :( please help!

Comment: I think this will help you: https://www.drupal.org/project/field_tools.

Answer (score 0):

you can definitely accomplish this with the migrate module (https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate). Your source DB and your destination DB will be the same, but that is acceptable. You're essentially migrating ContentA nodes into ContentB nodes and since they both have the same fields the mapping should be very simple.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, For example "ContentA" has A, B, C fields and "ContentB" has A, B, D fields, how i need to move it? Still can i use this module?

Comment: Absolutely ... you can specify a mapping of what to do with the source data and how to put it into the destination. This module is definitely your best bet IMO